# How can i write class method such that it's argument not to be changed?

Tags: python, class, methods

In a python class with some methods i have:

```
def method0(self,x,y,z):
 s=x
 s=method1(self,s,y)
 s=method2(self,s,z)
 return s
```

When i run above code (which i don't want x to be changed) **x** changes along with **s**.(Why?)
But when i use copy module x doesn't change:

```
def method0(self,x,y,z):
 s=copy.copy(x)
 s=method1(self,s,y)
 s=method2(self,s,z)
 return s
```

How can i write **method0** such that x not to be changed?

Comment: You already did that.

Comment: I don't want to use **copy**! Isn't another way?

Comment: How about using a constructor?

Comment: @REACHUS I don't know about it...Could you write it for my case?

Comment: @REACHUS what is a constructor to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly the way you did - by copying values before you modify them. Python has no notion of constness such as C++ (which isn't too great anyhow), so there is no way to enforce you only use non-mutating operations on your arguments.

And there is also no way to declare an argument to be passed as copy, not as reference.

If you know your domain (e.g. in your case the matrices), you could try & make this approach a bit more declarative by copying arguments in a decorator.

```
 from copy import deepcopy
 from functools import wraps

 def deepcopied(f):
     @wraps(f)
     def _d(*args, **kwargs):
         real_args = []
         real_kwargs = {}
         for arg in args:
             if isinstance(arg, (list, dict)):
                 arg = deepcopy(arg)
             real_args.append(arg)
         for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
             if isinstance(value, (list, dict)):
                 value = deepcopy(value)
             real_kwargs[key] = value
         return f(*real_args, **real_kwargs)
     return _d


 @deepcopied
 def foo(a, b=None):
     a.append("mutated!")
     if b is not None:
         b["bar"].append("mutated")


 one = list()
 two = dict(bar=list())

 foo(one, two)
 print one, two
```

Answer (score 1):

The other way to prevent x from being changed is to make sure that none of your functions ever change their argument.  Your problem stems from the fact that either method1 or method2 is changing their argument.  But you are also returning the value from those methods.  Fix those methods to not change the matrices passed into them, and only to make new matrices, and you will have fixed the problem.